# How do I install Ubuntu on laptop with broken screen

Tags: installation

I have an old laptop with a broken screen so I can't see any text on the right 3/4 of the screen... just a small strip on the left from top to bottom is visible.

I have the laptop connected to my LCD TV but nothing appears on it until the laptop boot gets to the windows logon screen. I want to replace windows vista with Ubuntu but can't see the screen on the laptop to change boot sequence to install by USB or CD.

I've investigated the option to install using the windows installer but it looks like this option will create a duel OS and I don't want that. I'm a complete noob to Ubuntu. My goal is to set up a media center using laptop/PS3/XBMC/TV.

Comment: Does your laptop keyboard have a `screen redirect` kind of key, like Fn + f4 or something? If yes, did u try that?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. I did this once with a laptop of a friend (he wanted to use his laptop which had a broken graphic card as a server, he has used it for a year as a minecraft, irc, plex, owncloud and subsonic server). The final way to install ubuntu was to remove the hard drive, insert the hard drive into another laptop, install ubuntu and then put the hard drive back again. Before you put the hdd back, you should install openssh-server. After you put the hdd back, you can control your laptop remotely (google for putty/xming if you're using windows or type `ssh -X username@lan-ip-address` in a terminal on a linux pc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that will be impossible. In OS installation (even Windows), it can only display using internal LCD, it is after the installation then you can configure your OS to use which display. The only option is to get the screen fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a laptop with the build-in screen broken and I managed to change the display settings with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and continue with the installation of Ubuntu 20.4 through the external monitor(VGA)

I had to do this as the first thing and blindly when the installer stopped and required the user input for the next steps.

Below a picture, I hope it helps

Regards,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Using data medium transplantation

You could take out the internal hard disk or SSD of the laptop and plug it into another PC. Then use that PC to install Ubuntu on the disk, transplant the disk back into the laptop and you're good to go.

### Using automated / unattended installation

You could create an Ubuntu installer that works automated or unattended. There are various tools available.