# Unable to install Ubuntu on a laptop with broken screen with second screen connected as alternative

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, screen

I have a Toshiba Laptop with a broken screen. I was able to connect it to VGA input of LG TV. I was able to install Windows 10. Now I want to have dual boot and have Ubuntu as an option.

I made a boot-able USB stick and I was able to boot with installer. First screen displayed OK, then I saw the file system checking process. Then display turned black, and I heard melody played.

My problem is: I can't continue installation. The installer is not showing the process. In other post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398494/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-laptop-with-broken-screen) it stated, that it is not possible (the post is more than 6 y.o.). 1) Another option is to install Ubuntu on another PC with a working screen. 2) I am thinking to have a script or config file to do a silent install. But I will need to configure space for Ubuntu and Windows.

Any other recommendations?
Thank you!

Comment: I think there is definitely a way.  Look at your laptop keyboard.  There may be hardware keys that change the way the monitor(s) are configure.  Try those.  If that doesn't work try to get into the BIOS of your laptop and disable the screen.  Or there may be a setting to force VGA out.

Comment: Hi. Yes. I tried to switch with the key FN + Display Switch. It did not help. Screen remain black. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have a laptop with the build-in screen broken and I managed to change the display settings with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and continue with the installation of Ubuntu 20.4 through the external monitor(VGA)

I had to do this as the first thing and blindly when the installer stopped and required the user input for the next steps.

Below a picture, I hope it helps

Regards,

[image: display_selector_screenshot]